# How to join left join with join

Tags: sql-server

Suppose i have 5 tables 
Let say AIM,BB,Cust,Dc and Emp . Each table have some common id say cid
So i want some data  from each table but for last table i want left join from first table. So how do i write the query.

```
Select 
   a.column, 
   b.column, 
   c.column , 
   d.column 
from
   AIM a,
   BB b,
   Cust c,
   Dc d,
   Emp e
Where 
   a.cid = b.cid 
   and a.cid = c.cid 
   and a.cid = d.cid
```

Now my 4 tables joined but how do i apply left join to fifth table from first

Comment: You don't... Get out of the habit of using the old ANSI89 going syntax. It's been phased out in favor of the ANSI 92 syntax.

Comment: You could place the first columsn in a subselect and left join it on the last.

Answer (score 0):

You're not restricted to joining your tables ONLY from the table which immediately precedes it. You'd just do

```
... left outer join emp e
        on a.CID = e.CID
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your query to use explicit join.

```
Select 
   a.column, 
   b.column, 
   c.column, 
   d.column,
   e.column
from
    AIM a
    inner join 
        BB b on 
        b.cid = a.cid
    inner join
        Cust c on
        c.cit = a.cid
    inner join
        Dc d on
        d.cid = a.cid
    left join
        Emp e on
        e.cid = a.cid   --or what ever condition
```

[bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)